# How we can enable readonly textarea vertical scroll bars

Tags: html, css

I am using a readonly textarea but vertical scrollbars are disabled. How we can enable readonly textarea vertical scroll bars?

```html
<textarea id="txtMailTo" 
          style="width: 615px;display: inline-block ;overflow-y:scroll" 
          readonly>
</textarea>
```

[image]

Comment: If you put text into the HTML for the text area, it works as expected. You must have something else that is stopping it from working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need to set `height` on the `<textarea> element`:

```css
textarea {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="txtMailTo" style="width: 615px;display: inline-block ;overflow-y:scroll" row="10" readonly>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Tempor orci eu lobortis elementum. Justo laoreet sit amet cursus sit amet. Tincidunt dui ut ornare lectus sit amet est placerat in. Pellentesque massa placerat duis ultricies lacus. Viverra accumsan in nisl nisi scelerisque eu. Viverra adipiscing at in tellus integer. Dictum non consectetur a erat nam at lectus. Cursus metus aliquam eleifend mi in. Non nisi est sit amet facilisis. Suspendisse ultrices gravida dictum fusce ut placerat.

Ullamcorper dignissim cras tincidunt lobortis feugiat vivamus at augue eget. Dictum non consectetur a erat nam at lectus. Leo a diam sollicitudin tempor id eu nisl nunc. Libero id faucibus nisl tincidunt eget nullam. Sit amet aliquam id diam. Tortor vitae purus faucibus ornare suspendisse sed nisi. Tortor aliquam nulla facilisi cras. Tellus cras adipiscing enim eu turpis egestas. Id porta nibh venenatis cras sed felis eget. Tellus at urna condimentum mattis pellentesque id.

Tellus integer feugiat scelerisque varius morbi. Non odio euismod lacinia at quis risus sed vulputate. Ultricies integer quis auctor elit sed vulputate mi. Ut eu sem integer vitae. Laoreet sit amet cursus sit amet. Massa sed elementum tempus egestas sed sed risus pretium. Egestas purus viverra accumsan in nisl nisi scelerisque eu ultrices. Vivamus at augue eget arcu dictum varius duis at consectetur. Mattis vulputate enim nulla aliquet porttitor lacus luctus accumsan tortor. Laoreet suspendisse interdum consectetur libero id faucibus nisl. Sit amet venenatis urna cursus eget nunc. In fermentum posuere urna nec tincidunt praesent. Viverra tellus in hac habitasse platea. Neque volutpat ac tincidunt vitae semper.

Neque gravida in fermentum et sollicitudin. Congue nisi vitae suscipit tellus mauris. Urna nunc id cursus metus. Elementum nibh tellus molestie nunc non blandit massa. In tellus integer feugiat scelerisque varius morbi enim nunc. Consectetur a erat nam at lectus urna. Turpis tincidunt id aliquet risus feugiat in ante metus dictum. Tellus elementum sagittis vitae et leo duis. Nisi vitae suscipit tellus mauris a. Suspendisse potenti nullam ac tortor vitae purus faucibus ornare suspendisse. Suspendisse potenti nullam ac tortor vitae purus faucibus ornare suspendisse. Turpis massa sed elementum tempus egestas sed sed risus pretium. Sollicitudin tempor id eu nisl nunc mi. Sed blandit libero volutpat sed. Nullam vehicula ipsum a arcu cursus vitae congue. Ultrices vitae auctor eu augue ut lectus. Vestibulum mattis ullamcorper velit sed ullamcorper morbi. Sagittis id consectetur purus ut.

Cursus metus aliquam eleifend mi in nulla posuere. Adipiscing vitae proin sagittis nisl rhoncus mattis rhoncus. Curabitur vitae nunc sed velit dignissim sodales ut eu. Nibh sit amet commodo nulla facilisi nullam vehicula ipsum. Aliquam sem fringilla ut morbi. Nascetur ridiculus mus mauris vitae ultricies leo integer malesuada nunc. Sed viverra ipsum nunc aliquet bibendum enim facilisis. Fringilla phasellus faucibus scelerisque eleifend donec. Rhoncus mattis rhoncus urna neque viverra justo nec. Nisl condimentum id venenatis a condimentum vitae sapien pellentesque. Accumsan tortor posuere ac ut. Suspendisse interdum consectetur libero id faucibus nisl. Risus ultricies tristique nulla aliquet enim.
</textarea>
```

Good Luck...

Comment: it is worked in normal websites, if we use any internal company frameworks it is not worked out...finally i used the <div> instead of <textarea>.                                                              <div id="mail" style=" margin-left: 155px;width: 608px;height: 50px;overflow-y: scroll;overflow-x: scroll;outline: solid black 1px;border: solid gray 0.5px;word-break: break-word;">

                    </div>